# Derived tables in Linq to SQL

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I would like to implement this in Linq to SQL:

```
select * from (
    select * from Orders) as A
```

Obviously this is a pointless example, but I just can't figure out how to do it!

Comment: So your question is more 'how to do derived tables in Linq-to-Sql' ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I didn't know they were called derived tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var subquery = from row in Orders select row;
var query = from row in subquery select row;
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for your response. Yes, I had thought of that. Any ideas on whether it can be combined into one "query"?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var dc = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
             var A = from ordOuter in
                 from ordInner in dc.Orders
                 select ordInner
             select ordOuter;
}
```