# Convert SQL inner select to Linq to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Can some one help me to convert this to Linq to SQL

```
SELECT
   a.dtCreated, COUNT(a.dtCreated) 
FROM 
    (SELECT     
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dtCreated, 106) AS dtCreated
     FROM tblNotes) a
GROUP BY 
    a.dtCreated
ORDER BY 
    a.dtCreated
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Derived tables in Linq to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430383/derived-tables-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined your language so:

C#

```
var query = tblNotes
    .GroupBy(x=>x.dtCreated)
    .Select
    (
        x => new 
        {
            dtCreated = x.Key.ToString("dd mmm yyyy"), 
            Count = x.Count()
        }
    )
    .OrderBy(x=>x.dtCreated);
```

VB

```
Dim query = tblNotes.GroupBy(Function(x) x.dtCreated) _
    .Select(Function(x) New With _
        { _
            .dtCreated = x.Key.ToString("dd mmm yyyy"), _
            .Count = x.Count() _
        }) _
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.dtCreated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dtCreated` is a `datetime` and has a time component that you want to eliminate, and further assuming that you want to still treat `dtCreated` as a date for sorting purposes:

```
var q1 = tblNotes.GroupBy(n => n.dtCreated.Date)  // Group by the Date property of this DateTime
                 .OrderBy(g => g.Key)  // Order by the key, which is the Date portion of dtCreated
                 .Select(g => new 
                     { 
                          dtCreated = g.Key.ToString("dd mmm yyyy"), 
                          Count = g.Count()
                     });
```